# Selecing a large number of data points in column

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata

I have a `DataFrame` with 6 columns and over 26 million rows named `data`:

```
id, redshift, treeID
2,  0.0,      100000
5,  0.0,      340000
...
39495, 0.0,   500000
```

I also have a `list` of `treeID` with 600,000 entries:

```
id = [100000,490000, ... 500000]
```

I want to create a new `list` with only the `treeIDs` in `data` equal to the `id`s in `list`. The code that I was trying was

```
list = []
for x in id:
    transition = data[data['treeID'] == x]
    list.append(transition)
```

Then I would just use `pandas.concat([list,0])` which would merge all the different arrays.

However, this is insanely slow, taking about 3 hours to go through this list and I have 60 of these files. Is there any way to speed this process up?

I thought about dividing the initial data file into several smaller `DataFrame` and then parallelize it but that seems like bad form.

Is there a better way or is that the best way to deal with these large datasets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also

```
transition = data[data['treeId'].isin(id)]
```

Comment: This was just what I was looking for! It now takes about 20 seconds instead of 3 hours.